# use javascript code of html page in mainactivity.php

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have created a small project.. in which i used multiple techniques..
here the concept goes:

1. In android project I have 3 `XML` pages
2. First two are the basic one, in the third page I used `WebView`
3. It displays a `calender` (in asset folder I have my `HTML` page and `.js, .css` files which supports the calender to work)
4. I displayed a `Calender` and selected date in `HTML` page

code is:

```
var calendarPicker1 = $("#dsel1").calendarPicker({
    monthNames:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    dayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    useWheel:true,
    callbackDelay:500,
    years:1,
    months:3,
    days:4,
    showDayArrows:false,
    callback:function(cal) //this function displays the selected date
    {
      $("#wtf").html("Selected date: " + cal.currentDate);
    }    
    });
```

Now I have to pass he selected date to database.. So I've added another function which returns the selected date

code::

```
function getStringToMyAndroid()
     {
        var date = cal.currentDate;
        return date;
        window.AndroidApp.receiveString(date);
     }
```

In `MainActivity.java` I've added

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    void receiveString(String value) 
    {
        Log.d("MyApp", value);        
    }   
}

myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "calender");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:getStringToMyAndroid()");
```

But when I am sending that data to database

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bday",value);
```

it giving error at value..
How can i pass the selected date to database..

any help in solving this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .html page

```
var calendarPicker1 = $("#dsel1").calendarPicker({
    monthNames:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    dayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    useWheel:true,
    months:1,
   days:3,
    callback:function(cal) 
    {
      $("#date").html("Selected date: " + cal.currentDate);       
        var date = cal.currentDate.toDateString(); 
        calender.receiveString(date);
    }   

 });
```

In MainActivity.java

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void receiveString(String value) 
        {
            MainActivity.this.date=value ;
        }   
    }
```

OnCreate()

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "calender");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:getStringToMyAndroid()");
```

to save it database:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bday",date));
```

Job Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("location of your file");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 Log.i("Prabhakar",_rseponse);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response @Prabhakar,where do we need to call this method

Comment: call this method in oncreate within the handler or use AsyncTask